# We have a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_9$ so that each member is $1$ or $-1$. Is it possible: $a_0a_1+a_1a_2+...+a_8a_9+a_9a_0=0$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, invariance

> We have a sequence $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_9$ so that each member is $1$ or $-1$. Is it possible: $$a_0a_1+a_1a_2+...+a_8a_9+a_9a_0=0$$

This problem was given on contest, but I don't know how to solve it.

Clearly we must have $5$ terms $a_ia_{i+1}$ equal $-1 $ and other $5$ equal $1$. I have created a graph in which $a_i$ is connected with $a_{i+1}$ (modulo 10) if their product is -1. So we have $5$ edges and we can write handshake lemma $$\sum_{i=0}^9 d_i=10$$
where $d_i \in \{0,1,2\}$, but all this is usless.

I tried to find a configuration but failed every time. Any idea? For sure there must be simple argumentation why this does not hold or simple configuration why it does. Just don't see.

Answer (score 6):

No assignment of the $a_i$ will satisfy the given constraint, and the "simple argumentation" is as follows.
$$\begin{matrix}
a_0&a_1&a_2&a_3\\
a_9&&&a_4\\
a_8&a_7&a_6&a_5
\end{matrix}$$
The ten terms of the sum are products of consecutive values in the above loop. The $a_i$ form alternating runs of $+1$ and $-1$, and since this is a loop, there must be an even number of runs, thus an even number of *boundaries* between runs, hence an even number of $-1$ terms in the sum.

But we require exactly five $-1$ terms in the sum for it to be zero. Thus, no assignment of the $a_i$ can satisfy the sum.

Answer (score 6):

The sum is congruent to $2 \pmod 4.$ This is the case if all the variables are set to $+1.$ If we negate any single variable compared with whatever it was, we change the sum by either $0$ or $ \pm 4,$ in any case keeping the same value $\pmod 4$

Comment: Like: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785242/need-help-in-proving-that-4-divides-n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @MariaMazur yes, same thing. however, the way I got this was to consider the same problem for a single variable, then for 2, where it was clear we got $a_0 a_1 + a_1 a_0 = \pm 2$

Comment: @Maria I explain this method more algebraically in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The hint.

Take the product of these ten addends.

I got that it's impossible.

Comment: That's what I call a hint :-)

Answer (score 3):

Letting $a_i = 2 b_i -1 $ (with $b_i\in \{0,1\}$), each term of the sum has the form $$a_i a_{i+1}= 4 b_i b_{i+1}-2b_i -2b_{i+1}+1$$

(the sum in the index $_{i+1}$ is assumed to be cyclic, of course).

Hence summing over all the terms we want

$$ 4 P -4 S +10=0 \iff 2 (P-S) =5$$

with $P= \sum  b_i b_{i+1}$ and $S=\sum b_i$. Because both $P$ and $S$ are integers, the equality cannot be true.

BTW, this shows that, in general, the equality can only be true if the number of elements is divisible by $4$.

Comment: How you came up with this idea?

Comment: Well, the mapping $\{-1,1\} \leftrightarrow \{0,1\}$ is quite common. This is similar to  Will Jagy's answer, but I found it a little easier to operate within the naturals.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cycle of length $10$ with the vertices numbered from $0$ to $9$ along the cycle. Now collapse together every run of consecutive vertices sharing the same value of the corresponding variable $a_n$. You will get a pentagon with the vertices of alternating signs, which is impossible.

Comment: This is basicly the same as Parcly Taxel solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ $ The sum as a function of $\,a_i\,$ is $\,\color{#0a0}{f(a_i)} = (\overbrace{a_{i-1}+a_{i+1}}^{\large \rm \color{#c00}{odd\,\  +\,\ odd}})\,a_i + k\ $ so by the Lemma its value $\!\bmod 4\,$ is *invariant* under $\,a_i\to -a_i\,$ so is the same as when all $\,a_i = 1,\,$ so $\,\equiv 10\equiv 2\pmod{\!4}$

**Lemma** $\  f(a) \equiv f(-a)\, \pmod{\! 4}\,\ $ if   $\ \color{#0a0}{f(x)}\, =\, \color{#c00}{2j}\, x + k,\ $ for $\ a,j,k\in\Bbb Z$

**Proof** $\ \ \ \ f(a)\,-\,f(-a)\, =\, (2ja+k)-(-2ja+k)\, =\, 4ja\,\equiv\, 0\pmod{\!4}$